# Polynom subspace of continuously differentiable Functions

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathcal{C}^n(\mathbb{R})=:V$ and $$\langle f,g\rangle :=\sum_{k=0}^n {f^{(k)}(a)g^{(k)}(a)}$$ is a positive semidefinite Bilinear Form for all $f,g\in V$.  Therefore I need to give one $f\in V,f\neq0:  \langle f,f\rangle=0$. $f$ depends on $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Then **a)**
$W:=\{ f\in V| \exists F\in \mathbb{R[x]}:\forall t\in \mathbb{R}:F(t)=f(t)\land \deg(F)\le n\}$, prove that for all $f\in V$ there exists exactly one $p\in W$ with ($\forall q\in W$) $$f-p\bot q $$
and **b)** $T:V\rightarrow W$ with $$\forall f\in V:\forall q\in W:\langle f-T(f),q\rangle = 0$$ is linear and give $T(\exp),T(\sin)$ with $a=0$.

For **b)**:
Let $\lambda ,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g\in V$. Then:
$$T(\lambda f+\mu g)\underset{a)}=\lambda p+\mu q\underset{a)}=\lambda T(f)+\mu T(g), $$ so $T$ is linear and $T(\exp(a))=T(1)=1$ because:
$$0=\langle \exp-T(\exp),q\rangle =\sum_{k=0}^{n}(exp^{(k)}(a)-T^{(k)}(\exp(a)))q^{(k)}(a)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(1^{(k)}-T^{(k)}(1))q^{(k)}(0)=1-T(1)+0-T'(1)\underset{T=1}=0$$ and
$T(\sin(a))=T(0)=0$, $T$ linear:
$$\langle \sin-T(\sin),q\rangle =\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-T^{(k)}(0))q^{k}(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-T^{(k)}(0))\underset{T=0}=0.$$
Can someone help me with **a)** and hopefully confirm **b)**? Any tips are appreciated!
Thanks for reading!